# Longest ExecStart command line

Tags: ubuntu, systemd

I have been reviewing a lot of systemd job files, and found a systemd unit file on Ubuntu 20.04.2 with a ExecStart command that is 4284 characters long, it occurred to me to ask - what is the maximum length permitted?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [`man systemd.syntax`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.syntax.html):

> The limit on line length is very large (currently 1 MB), but it is
> recommended to avoid such long lines and use multiple directives,
> variable substitution, or other mechanism as appropriate for the given
> file type.

I'd expect a long command line to run into problems with `ARG_MAX` first given the very permissible line length size.